# Can't connect to modbus RTU over TCP. What is wrong?

Tags: python, modbus

Prove that device is working: `./modpoll -m enc -p4660 -t4:float -r60 -a3 192.168.1.1`:

```
Protocol configuration: Encapsulated RTU over TCP
Slave configuration...: address = 3, start reference = 60, count = 1
Communication.........: 192.168.1.1, port 4660, t/o 1.00 s, poll rate 1000 ms
Data type.............: 32-bit float, output (holding) register table

TRACELOG: Set poll delay 0
TRACELOG: Set port 4660
TRACELOG: Open connection to 192.168.1.1
TRACELOG: Configuration: 1000, 1000, 0
-- Polling slave... (Ctrl-C to stop)
TRACELOG: Read multiple floats 3 60
TRACELOG: Send(6): 03 03 00 3B 00 02 
TRACELOG: Recv(9): 03 03 04 6E 08 42 F7 35 FF 
[60]: 123.714905
```

And how I try to get the connection with `pymodbus` library:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer

ModbusTcpClient(host='192.168.1.1', port=4660, framer=ModbusRtuFramer, timeout=5)
client.connect() # returns True
client.read_holding_registers(60, count=3, unit=0x03)
```

And get this result:

```
pymodbus.exceptions.ConnectionException: Modbus Error: [Connection] 192.168.1.1:4660
Modbus Error: [Connection] 192.168.1.1:4660
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Oddly enough when I left work a few hours ago I left with a very similar problem that I can't work on until tomorrow. I'm curious - if you change `read_holding_registers(60, count=3, unit=0x03)` to `read_holding_registers(10, count=3, unit=0x03)` do you still get an error? They might not hold any data but I'm just wondering if the error goes away

Comment: @roganjosh, yes. I still get an error.

Comment: For your issue, I'm not sure I understand specifically what `./modpoll -m enc -p4660 -t4:float -r60 -a3 192.168.1.1:` does, but `Slave configuration...: address = 3, start reference = 60, count = 1` does say `count = 1`. Presumably not the issue but I noticed it so raised.

Comment: @roganjosh, wow! Interesting behavior.
1) When a parameter is wrong - it raises connection error.
2) Connection not stable, sometimes Error raises with right registers parameters. (maybe problem in my device)

Comment: Then you're seeing what I have observed today. connection error really doesn't make much sense, but seems to be a default go-to when something goes wrong. There's other subtleties I found like [this](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/master/pymodbus/register_read_message.py#L182) - I'm struggling to see how it works properly, but that whole module only does `doException(merror.IllegalValue)` and `self.doException(merror.IllegalAddress)` so it's possible it also results in connection error.

Comment: I raised this in chat and it's possible that we're facing different issues that are confounded a bit by how exceptions work in the library. I won't delete my comments but there's also nothing to say that they give a starting point for your issue sorry.

Comment: I fixed my issue today. I can't read all my populated registers at once (restriction seems to be in PLC, not library) I had to do in blocks of 50 and concatenate the responses. However, what it did show me was that the error can originate as a hex code in the unit, which is received by pymodbus and then used to raise exception. Using `result = client.read_holding_registers(60, count=3, unit=0x03)` will give you an exception object that you can call `dir()` on and try to investigate the exception in a lower level; for example, the modbus exception code which can then be searched online.

Comment: @roganjosh I know about codes, and already have validation in my code, but in my case client.read return nothing (exception raised inside pymodbus logic).